# Initialize a Entity Data Model in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am struggling quite a bit with the following question. I have a WCF Service which contains a Entity Data Model. Actually this model is initialized with all the data contained within the underlying table, so at runtime it contains all the data. What I need is to have only certain data in my Entity Data Model.

Is it possible to initialize my Entity Data Model with a subset of the data stored in the database table? Lets say by giving a patricular where-clause somewhere?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks all and kind regards
Sandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand the concepts. 
Entity Data Model just describes the structure of data using concepts like entity type, association type, and property. An instance of an entity type is what actually describes an object like a Customer, a Category etc and this is what is actually mapped to the underlying table.

That being said, there are many ways to filter your data, one of the most familiar being linq. Here are some resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/queries-in-linq-to-entities